# How to dynamically populate Calendar marked dates from api - React Native, redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, redux

As title said I need to populate marked dates which im getting from API in Calendar component (i am using "react-native-calendars": "^1.403.0").

```
enter code here : <Calendar
    markedDates={{
       "2020-09-15": { selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: "blue" },
       "2020-09-05": { selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: "blue" },
       }}/>
```

This is working fine, but my problem is how to dynamically mark days from API. here is my code

const calendar returns when im logging

```
Array [
   Object {
    "course_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-09-08T12:52:05.000000Z",
    "date": "2020-09-25",
    "description": "Amet quas nemo aliquid cupiditate libero deserunt et excepturi.",
    "group_id": 1,
    "homework": "Illo eveniet est et non molestiae ut ab atque.",
     "id": 571,
    "time_duration": 89,
    "time_start": "14:49:37",
    "title": "Ms.",
    "updated_at": "2020-09-08T12:52:05.000000Z",
   },
  Object {
    "course_id": 1,
     "created_at": "2020-09-08T12:52:09.000000Z",
     "date": "2020-09-30",
    "description": "Earum similique molestiae sunt praesentium et ea iste deserunt.",
    "group_id": 1,
    "homework": "Autem aspernatur beatae in rerum rerum sit harum quis.",
    "id": 831,
     "time_duration": 89,
    "time_start": "21:53:01",
    "title": "Prof.",
    "updated_at": "2020-09-08T12:52:09.000000Z",
   },
 ]
```

here is whole code:

```
  const CalendarScreen = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const access_token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
  const calendar = useSelector((state) => state.calendarClasses.calendar);
  const isCalendarLoading = useSelector(
    (state) => state.calendarClasses.isCalendarLoading
  );

  const obj = Object.fromEntries(calendar.map((item) => ["date", item.date]));

  let day= JSON.stringify(obj.date);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadCalendar());
    dispatch(getCalendar(access_token, childId));
  }, [dispatch, getCalendar]);


  return (
      <Calendar
        markedDates={{
          day: { selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: "blue" },
      
        }}
/>
```

Every suggestion will be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

```
 const CalendarScreen = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const access_token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
  const calendar = useSelector((state) => state.calendarClasses.calendar);
  const isCalendarLoading = useSelector(
    (state) => state.calendarClasses.isCalendarLoading
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadCalendar());
    dispatch(getCalendar(access_token, childId));
  }, [dispatch, getCalendar]);

  let markedDay = {};

  calendar.map((item) => {
    markedDay[item.date] = {
      selected: true,
      marked: true,
      selectedColor: "purple",
    };
  });


  return (
      <Calendar markedDates={ markedDay }
        ...
    />
}
```

Pay attention in component Calendar - markedDates = { } , markedDates must be in with single {}, because markedDay is object. So you cant set like it is in documentation <Calendar markedDatse={{ markedDay }} /> because this will be like markedDates= {{{ }}}.

Comment: I want to set different dates with different colors. Is there somethin wrong with this:
` 
markedDates={{
                [fechaInicioContrato]: {selected: true, selectedColor: "green" },
                [fechaFinContrato]: {selected: true, selectedColor: "red" },
              }}
`

Answer (score 4):

You are only missing some square brackets around the date:

```
markedDates={{
  [day]: { selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: "blue" },
}}
```